# Using AntLR 4 to get names of variables and functions

Tags: java, c, parsing, antlr4

I have a set of source code files written in C language and I need to generate a parse to extract the names of variables and functions from the files.

I found out that I can do this with AntLR. I already have a C grammar, but I don't what are the steps I should follow to what I said.

Please someone give me a hint of how to proceed, for example, should I generate a listener or a visitor?

Thank you!

Comment: Give something a try first. Feel free to ask a more specific question when you run into problems. Your question as it now stands is a bit too broad, IMO.

Comment: Ok, I've been trying to do it, but I'm having problems, if you could help me by checking this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305232/using-antlr-to-get-identifiers-and-function-names ,please

Answer (score 4):

### Short answer

Antlr generates the listener interface for you. So you just need to implement this interface and then use the instance of your implementation to walk the parse tree.

---

### Long Answer

Antlr is a parser generator, so if you haven't done it already, generate the parser source code using your grammar file.

Assuming your C grammar is in a file named `TheC.g4`, use `antlr4` to generate source:

`antlr4 TheC.g4`

The output of this step are several generated java source files containing the parser implementation. You can compile the source with `javac` like:

`javac TheC*.java`

Now you can write your own java code that use the above generated lexer and parser classes to parse your C source file.

```
TheCLexer lexer = new TheCLexer(input); // use the generated lexer to tokenize the C source
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
TheCParser parser = new TheCParser(tokens);
ParserRuleContext<Token> tree = parser.compilationUnit(); // <<--This part will be different for you depending on the root of your grammar
```

Now that you have the parse tree, you can use your own implementation of the generated listener interface `TheCListener` to consume the tree

```
ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker(); // create standard walker
MyListener extractor = new MyListener(parser); // MyListener is your implementation of TheCListener interface
walker.walk(extractor, tree); // initiate walk of tree with listener
```

*Note:* All the above code samples are adapted from this [page](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Parse+Tree+Listeners)

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I've been trying to do it, but I'm having problems, if you could help me again by checking this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305232/using-antlr-to-get-identifiers-and-function-names, please.