# Using Antlr to get identifiers and function names

Tags: java, c, antlr

I'm trying to use and understand AntLR, this is new to me. My purpose is to read a source code file written in C and extract from it the identifiers (variables and function names).

In my C grammar (file **C.g4**) consider:

```
identifierList
    :   Identifier
    |   identifierList Comma Identifier
    ;
Identifier
    :   IdentifierNondigit
        (   IdentifierNondigit
        |   Digit
        )*
    ;
```

After generation of parser and listener I create my own listener to the identifierList.

Note that MyCListener class extends CBaseListener:

```
public class MyCListener extends CBaseListener {


@Override
public void enterIdentifierList(CParser.IdentifierListContext ctx) {
    List<ParseTree> children = ctx.children;
    for (ParseTree parseTree : children) {
        System.out.println(parseTree.getText());
    }

}
```

Then I have this in main class:

```
 String fileurl = "C:/example.c";

 CLexer lexer;
 try {
       lexer = new CLexer(new ANTLRFileStream(fileurl));
       CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
       CParser parser = new CParser(tokens);

       CParser.IdentifierListContext identifierContext = parser.identifierList();
       ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
       MyCListener listener = new MyCListener();
       walker.walk(listener, identifierContext);

 } catch (IOException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
```

Where example.c is:

```
int main() {

// this is C

 int i=0; // i is int
 /* double j=0.0;
    C
 */
}
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Maybe I didn't write MyCListener properly, or identifierList is not what I need to listen... Really don't know. I'm sorry, but I didn't even understand my output, why is there a lexical error?:

```
line 3:4 mismatched input '(' expecting {<EOF>, ','}
main
(
)
{
int
i
=
0
;
}
```

As you see, I'm very confused about this. Can somebody help me ? Please...

Answer (score 5):

With this line:

```
CParser.IdentifierListContext identifierContext = parser.identifierList();
```

you're trying to parse your entire input as an `identifierList`. But your input isn't just that.

Assuming you're using the [`C.g4` from the ANTLR4 Github repository](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4), try to let the parser start at the entry point of the grammar (which is the rule `compilationUnit`):

```
MyCListener listener = new MyCListener();
ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(listener, parser.compilationUnit());
```

### EDIT

Here's a quick demo:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final List<String> identifiers = new ArrayList<String>();

        String source = "int main() {\n" +
                "\n" +
                "// this is C\n" +
                "\n" +
                " int i=0; // i is int\n" +
                " /* double j=0.0;\n" +
                "    C\n" +
                " */\n" +
                "}";

        CLexer lexer = new CLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(source));
        CParser parser = new CParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));

        ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(new CBaseListener(){

            @Override
            public void enterDirectDeclarator(@NotNull CParser.DirectDeclaratorContext ctx) {
                if (ctx.Identifier() != null) {
                    identifiers.add(ctx.Identifier().getText());
                }
            }

            // Perhaps override other rules that use `Identifier`

        }, parser.compilationUnit());

        System.out.println("identifiers -> " + identifiers);
    }
}
```

which would print:

```
identifiers -> [main, i]
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help. Please, how do I walk from the entry point and attach my listener to identifiers, so that, when it reaches an identifier I can save it in a ArrayList, for example?